# add custom dataset into fasttext classification deep learning

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, text-classification, fasttext

Based on this guithub link https://github.com/brightmart/text_classification, I want to running "**fasttext**" classification but there are some files that I couldn't find them so **I want to add my custom dataset on it as an *input*** and after that run it.
In github manual there is no instruction for adding our own dataset as an input?

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to have the load_file code, in [this snippet](https://github.com/brightmart/text_classification/blob/master/a01_FastText/p5_fastTextB_train.py#L49-L53) he have told you what the data/batch is like and I'd like to translate it into English for you:

```
print("testX.shape:", np.array(testX).shape)  # 2500 lists, with each list representing a sentence
# there are 2500 lists in testX each one standing for a sentence, 
# which means testX is a 2 dimensional list containing 2500 lists 
# and each list has several ids of words
print("testY.shape:", np.array(testY).shape)  # 2500 labels
# correspondingly there are 2500 labels in the testY which is a 
# one dimensional list
print("testX[0]:", testX[0])  # [17, 25, 10, 406, 26, 14, 56, 61, 62, 323, 4]
# this is what the first sentence in testX like (all ids)
print("testX[1]:", testX[1]);
print("testY[0]:", testY[0]) # 0 ;print("testY[1]:",testY[1]) #0
```

You can make your own testX and testY which are both just list.